# How to represent JSON object for Map collection type for mentioned pattern?

Tags: java, json

```
Map<String,String> c1=new HashMap();
c1.put("key1","value1");
c1.put("key2","value2");

Map<String,HashMap> c2=new HashMap();
c2.put("key11",c1);
c2.put("key12",c1);


Map<String,HashMap> c3=new HashMap();
c3.put("key111",c2);
c3.put("key112",c2);
```

I have the data in above format how do I serialize it as JSON object that is how to represent above data format in JSON.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**How do I serialize it as JSON object ?**

Better use some open source JSON libraries like GSON,JACKSON etc. We are using GSON.

```
public class MyJson {
private static Gson gson = new Gson();
public static <T> T fromJson(Type type,
 TalosDeserializer deserializer,String json) {
     final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
     gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(type, deserializer);        
     final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();         
    return gson.fromJson(json,type);
}
public static String toJson(Object input) {
    return gson.toJson(input);
}
public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
    return gson.fromJson(json, classOfT);
}
```

}